# Showing that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty 1/n^z$ defines a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

> Show that the series
>    $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$$
>   defines a holomorphic function on the set $\{z \in \Bbb{C}\ :\ \operatorname{Re}(z) > 1\}$.

Does it suffice to show that the function is analytic - for instance, by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations? If so, what is the geometric representation of this series?

Comment: This is the riemann zeta function .

Comment: And yes, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are enough, but you have to prove the partial derivatives first (which is what I did, without using any theorem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Euler Product formula for Riemann zeta function proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742890/euler-product-formula-for-riemann-zeta-function-proof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).  You might benefit from reading the linked article and then going on from there.  You might also benefit from reading about [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) and their abscissae of convergence.

To your specific question, [this proof](http://planetmath.org/convergenceofriemannzetaseries) of the result uses elementary estimates and the $p$-test for convergence of a series.

Comment: Showing convergence is easy. It's analyticity that's harder.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a duplicate, but let me write the most elementary proof I know :*

If $g(z)$ is holomorphic and $|g''(z)| \le C$ then $$ \left|\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}-g'(z)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{h}\int_z^{z+h} (g'(u)-g'(z))du\right|=\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_z^{z+h}\int_z^u g''(v)dvdu\right|$$ $$\le \frac{1}{|h|}\int_z^{z+h}\int_z^u Cdvdu< |h| C$$
Now let $f_n(z) = n^{-z} = e^{-z \ln n}$, it is holomorphic with derivatives $f_n'(z)= -n^{-z} \ln n,f_n''(z)= n^{-z} \ln^2 n$ and for $Re(z) > 1+\epsilon$ : $|f_n''(z)| < n^{-1-\epsilon}\ln^2 n$.

Let $F(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(z) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-z} \ln n$, note it converges absolutely on $Re(z) > 1$, and for $Re(z) > 1+2\epsilon, |h| < \epsilon$ :
$$\left|\frac{\zeta(z+h)-\zeta(z)}{h}-F(z)\right| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)}{h}-f_n'(z)\right|\le|h|\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1-\epsilon}\ln^2 n$$
 i.e. for $Re(z) > 1+2\epsilon$ : 
$$\zeta'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\zeta(z+h)-\zeta(z)}{h} = F(z) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-z} \ln n$$
so that $\zeta(z)$ is holomorphic on $Re(z) > 1+2\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$,

and hence on $Re(z) > 1$.