# Proof that the Riemann Zeta Function is holomorphic on $Re(z)>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Ultimately I am trying to prove that that the Riemann Zeta function is holomorphic on $Re(z)>1$.

So far I have manipulated the series in the following way:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-zlogn}$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}cos(ylogn) - i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^x}sin(ylogn)$

From this point I have considered using the fact that a function, $f$ say, of a complex variable defined by a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$
with radius of convergence $R$ is holomorphic on an open disc $D(a,R)$. However, I really don't know how to go about this as I do not know what radius to choose as $Re(z)>1$ is obviously not a disc. Furthermore, I had no luck trying to find $R$ using the ratio test.

Do I need to continue manipulating the series into a more manageable form? Or am I approaching this problem in the wrong way?

Any help on what to try next would be great!

Comment: Not a good approach, I think. Use that a locally uniformly convergent series of holomorphic functions has a holomorphic sum.

Comment: Common functions have `\cos`, `\log`, and generally `\function_name`

Comment: See this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2013850/276986) for showing $\zeta'(z) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-z} \ln(n)$

Comment: I just saw [Showing that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty 1/n^z$ defines a holomorphic function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013814/showing-that-sum-limitsn-1-infty-1-nz-defines-a-holomorphic-function) pop up on the main list. This looks quite similar.

Answer (score 5):

For any $z$ so that $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt1$, the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^z}
$$
converges uniformly. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^z}\,\right|
&\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^{\mathrm{Re}(z)}}\\
&\le\frac1{\mathrm{Re}(z)-1}\frac1{N^{\mathrm{Re}(z)-1}}
\end{align}
$$
Since [the uniform limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368664/uniform-limit-of-holomorphic-functions) and each partial sum is holomorphic, the limit, $\zeta(z)$, is also holomorphic for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt1$.